# Find end of a .wave file to change the button String in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, time

I have a toggle button that reads a .wave file, and it's string changes to pause, and .....
my problem is that, when user plays a sound, and the button string changes to pause, after ending the sound, the string is still pause that I want to change it to play. But I don't know how can I find when the sound playing is ended, to change the button string to play?

I know I can find duration of sound by dividing length of sound signal to sample rate and make a delay function, but i am looking for better way like a particular function, is there exist something like that?

```
function Playb_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

global openS recS playS;

if(openS)
    if (state)
    set(hObject, 'String', 'Pause');
    resume(handles.p);
    else
        set(hObject, 'String', 'Play');
        pause(handles.p);
    end
end
   if(get(handles.p, 'Running')==0)
            set(hObject, 'String', 'Play');
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audioplayer object has 4 callback functions, one of them being being `StopFcn` which will be executed when the playback stops.

So just after when you defined your audioplayer, set this property to a function:

```
set( handle.p , 'StopFcn' , {@StopPlayback_Callback,handles.Playb} )
```

And somewhere in your code add the function which will change back the state of your button:

```
function StopPlayback_Callback(hObject, eventdata, buttonHandle )
    set( buttonHandle , 'String', 'Play' );
```

---

Note: the `handles.Playb` parameter sent to the function callback during the callback definition should be the actual handle of your button 'play/pause'. If your button handle has another name adjust this parameter to the real name.

---

In the same way, you could extend that to the start of the playback by using the `StartFcn`.

```
set( handle.p , 'StartFcn' , {@StartPlayback_Callback,handles.Playb} )
```

Then

```
function StartPlayback_Callback(hObject, eventdata, buttonHandle )
    set( buttonHandle , 'String', 'Pause' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `audioplayer` object for playback? If you are, then the object has a property called `running`, which is set to `on` while playback is active, and `off` while the audio playback is stopped. You could read the status of this property in order to show the correct status information.

**EDIT:**
My copy of Matlab is vurrently doing some calculations, so I cannot verify this right know, but if I rembember correctly, it is like this:
So if your audioplayer object is `handles.p`, you can read the property `Runnning` by addressing it like this `handles.p.Running`. This will then return `on` if the object is playing, and `off` if the playback has stopped.
However it seems like you are trying to do the check in a button callback. Be aware that the function will only be called when the button is pressed.

Comment: May you please explain how can I use running property? I've tried that with above code but I didn't succeed!

Comment: I added a bit about how to check the property in my answer above - I hope it helps!